Problem with cmd command formatting in rust
I have this code:
let output = Command::new("cmd")
        .args(&[
            "/C",
            r#"for /f "tokens=2,3 delims={,}" %a in ('"WMIC NICConfig where IPEnabled=True get DefaultIPGateway /value | find "I" "') do echo %~a"#,
        ])
        .output()?

If written into cmd directly command outputs ip of Default Gateway, I tested it, it works.
But I'm getting this error from code above:
Command failed with stderr: \"tokens=2,3 delims={,}\" was unexpected at this time.

I tried also using /" without r# - same error.
Error handling code:
if output.status.success() {
        let stdout = String::from_utf8(output.stdout)?.trim().to_string();

        if stdout.is_empty() {
            return Err(Box::new(MeasureLatencyError::DefaultGatewayError));
        }

        Ok(stdout)
    } else {
        // Handle the case where the command fails
        let stderr = String::from_utf8(output.stderr)?;
        eprintln!("Command failed with stderr: {}", stderr);
        Err(Box::new(MeasureLatencyError::DefaultGatewayError))
    }


cmd does some weird pre parsing of quoted things, you're much better of just calling WMIC NICConfig where IPEnabled=True get DefaultIPGateway /value as a Command directly and doing the logic in Rust.
